# Why this code does not output the result?

Tags: php, mysql

I get a don't get any errors or warning. My table is called products and the field is called name. I want to find the revelance between first and second column.

Why am I missing here?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost"," "," ");
mysql_select_db(" ");
mysql_query('set names utf8');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT t1.name AS first FROM products t1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (!$query) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

do {
    $first = $row['first'];
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT t1.name AS first,
                                 t2.name AS second,
                                 (MATCH (t2.name) AGAINST ('$first')) AS relevance
FROM products t1, products t2
                          WHERE t1.name = '$first'
                          ORDER BY relevance DESC");
if (!$query2) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
    $most_similar = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
?>
```

Comment: @Matt Boothman And the reason is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no t2 in your query, but in your select you have `t2.name as second`.

Actually, you don't have a `FROM` clause at all...

**Edit:**

This is a random guess at what you're trying to achieve...I don't really know, but you should be able to edit the query as needed.

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT '$first' AS first,
                             t.name AS second,
                             (MATCH (t.name) AGAINST ('$first')) AS relevance
                      FROM products t
                      ORDER BY relevance DESC");
```

Comment: Not really - I don't know what your t1 and t2 tables are supposed to be referencing or how they are related. I would need more information. But for giggles, see the edit anyway for a best guess at what I think you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check if $query2 is not FALSE and display an error with mysql_error() otherwise. See also the example on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php.